# Continua with Octopus deploy "RessourceNotFound" and breaking changes

Tags: octopus-deploy

I want to setup continua ci with octo deploy. In the past I was able to do it. but now with newer version of octodeploy it seems difficult

First continua didn't find a matching agent because the Octo.Default.Path wasn't resolved. I found out that it searches an octo.exe

but in the current octodeploy there is none
[image]

So I changed it to point to the octo.server.exe
Now the build starts but it gets a "ressource not found" response.
So i'm not sure i

The only [documentation I can find is from 2014](https://www.finalbuilder.com/resources/blogs/deployment-with-continua-ci-and-octopus-deploy)

Does somebody know if my change in the path is correct or even better if there is a more current documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Octo.Default` property collector in Continua CI is looking for the [Octopus CLI](https://octopus.com/downloads/octopuscli) executable. This needs to be installed on the agent, and added to the PATH of the Continua CI Agent service user, for the property collector to pick up the executable. The `Octo.Default` property collector is used for the `Octo Pack` and `Octo Push` actions. These actions are not required if using the MSBuild actions and Octopus Deploy build event handler as described in the blog you linked to. See also my reply to [your forum post](https://www.finalbuilder.com/forums/t/octopus-deploy-integration/6943).